# Android get PID of other applications

Tags: java, android

I would like to be able to start an activity or service and get the PID of that process as quickly as possible, immediately would be the best case scenario. Do I have any options other than browsing the /proc directory, which then leads to a variable-amount-of-time race condition between the time the activity/service is launched and the time it takes me to find what I want in the proc directory and begin observing?

Comment: Just curious, but what on earth for?

Comment: Apps components can be run on different process and components from different apps can share the same process, so there's no a one-to-one relationship, so it's pointless.

Comment: @john working on an application profiler for security purposes. It's important that I be able to get my monitoring tools in place and gathering data before the app spins up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you'd need to use ActivityManager: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html for the process info. You could:

1. Get all running app processes.
2. Find your app.
3. Get its PID.

Comment: Thanks. I fear this too will lead to a race condition between when I start the app to profile and get the PID, but it seems cleaner than browsing the /proc directory so you get a +1

Comment: Ah: if you're looking in another process for this then yes, there is some possibility you will not see it for an (undefined) little while. Not sure there is a better alternative though: let me know if you find one.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this on Android API 21 and above? I don't think RunningAppProcessInfo is exposed in Android L and above.

Comment: Is there a difference between google processes and normal app processes? 
If I check my running processes like this, I retrieve the current process of my own application. But the mobile is running Google Maps the same time, but I can't determine the Google Maps process.

(or is there any other way on how to retrieve google maps pid?)

Answer (score 7):

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pidsTask = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

for(int i = 0; i < pidsTask.size(); i++) {
    nameList.add(pidsTask.get(i).processName);
    idList.add(pidsTask.get(i).uid);
}
```

pidsTask.get(i).uid  // Return PID for Apps(Process)

Comment: the uid IS NOT the apps actual pid

for example, its pid may be 302 while its uid may be 10039

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
```

Comment: I had wanted the PID of other processes, not my own.

Comment: this answer is copied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454909/how-to-get-pid-of-android-application-with-out-using-adb-shell

Answer (score -1):

```
for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningProInfo : runningProcInfo) {

    int pid = runningProInfo.pid;

    Log.e(TAG+"-pid", ""+pid);

}
```

Where TAG = "Name_Of_Your_Activity"