# How to get pid of android application without using adb shell?

Tags: android, pid

How can I get an android application pid without using adb shell? Is there any API to get pid.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 112, accepted):

As every application has its own process id, one can get it by

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
```

Answer (score 17):

This also works:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
int processid = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
    if (info.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("here your package name")) {
       processid = info.pid;
    } 
}
```