# Get pid from the packageName

Tags: java, android

Now I was using the `app1` to start the `app2` from the packageName of `app2.` And then, I need to get the app2's `pid` and `uid`.

I have tried exec the shell `pidof` and `ps grep`, but it can only get the app1's `pid`.  I've also tried the function `getRunningAppProcesses()`, but without any effect. 
I supposed that if `Android 6.0` and above have done something for privacy protection? How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PID from package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296804/how-to-get-pid-from-package-name)

Comment: no, some method proposed in "How to get PID from package name" can't be used in adnroid 6.0 and above successfully. It can only return the pid of the request app itself