# Why does activity manager shows starting intent message?

Tags: java, android

In between of running my application activity manager just display message **I/ActivityManager(159): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.rfb.client/.RFB_ClientActivity bnds=[182,205][238,271] } from pid 159** it keeps on displaying this message.

Any idea why this info is shown in log ? what is the meaning of this message ?
Please let know if you know about this.

Log file:

```
04-20 23:57:02.339 D/RFB_MAIN(18199): RFB Activity started
04-20 23:57:02.339 I/ActivityManager(159): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.rfb.client/.RFB_Activity (has extras) } from pid 18199
04-20 23:57:02.359 W/ActivityManager(159): Trying to launch com.rfb.client/.RFB_Activity
04-20 23:57:02.429 D/RFB_Activity(18199): Opening RFB socket
04-20 23:57:02.719 D/RFB_Async(18199): Initiating
04-20 23:57:02.719 D/RFB_PROTOCOL(18199): Initializing SSL connection
04-20 23:57:02.719 D/RFB_PROTOCOL(18199): TrustStore - Initializing
04-20 23:57:02.729 I/ActivityManager(159): Displayed com.rfb.client/.RFB_Activity: +369ms
04-20 23:57:04.309 D/RFB_PROTOCOL(18199): TrustStore - Initialized
04-20 23:57:04.309 D/RFB_PROTOCOL(18199): KeyStore - Initializing
04-20 23:57:04.619 D/RFB_PROTOCOL(18199): KeyStore - Initialized
04-20 23:57:05.169 D/RFB_PROTOCOL(18199): Creating RFB socket
04-20 23:57:05.909 D/RFB_PROTOCOL(18199): RFB Socket created
04-20 23:57:20.749 I/ActivityManager(159): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.rfb.client/.RFB_ClientActivity bnds=[182,205][238,271] } from pid 159
04-20 23:57:43.729 I/ActivityManager(159): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.rfb.client/.RFB_ClientActivity bnds=[182,205][238,271] } from pid 159
04-20 23:58:35.289 I/ActivityManager(159): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.rfb.client/.RFB_ClientActivity bnds=[182,205][238,271] } from pid 159
```

Comment: do you use some url handlers ? What is the entry for this activity in your manifest ?

Comment: try this link for details

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039398/android-get-pid-of-other-applications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any idea why this info is shown in log ?

Because the Android engineer responsible for `ActivityManager` chose to log it. Frankly, I wish this engineer had not done this.

> what is the meaning of this message ?

It means Android is starting an activity, using the `Intent` described in the log message.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of action=main and category=launcher in intent filter is key make an entry point to android application and  will advertised in android manifest file. When android system try to launch an application, since main intent filter is present in the activity, activity manager gets control and catches the intent to start main process in main thread/UI thread.